# Determine the convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \sin \left(n \pi+\frac{1}{\ln n}\right)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I have to assess the convergence of

$$
\displaystyle
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \sin \left(n \pi+\frac{1}{\ln n}\right)
$$

I thought that it converges, because

$$
\displaystyle
\begin{eqnarray}
\sin (n \pi+\frac{1}{\ln n}) & = & \sin (n \pi) \cos \left(\frac{1}{\ln n}\right)+\cos (n \pi) \sin \left(\frac{1}{\ln n}\right)\\ & = & (-1)^n \sin \frac{1}{\ln n}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

And since $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^n\sin \frac{1}{\ln n}$ converges, so $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \sin \left(n \pi+\frac{1}{\ln n}\right)$ converges, too.

But I'm not sure $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^n\sin \frac{1}{\ln n}$ is conditional convergent or absolute convergent.

Is this approach right?

Comment: It's only conditional because $\sin\frac{1}{\ln n}\sim\frac{1}{\ln n}>\frac1n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sum(-1)^{n}\sin(\frac{1}{\ln(n)})$ converges by Leibniz Test .

But $\sum\sin(\frac{1}{\ln(n)})$ is divergent by comparing with $\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$.

That is $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{\ln(n)})}{\frac{1}{\ln(n)}}=1$$ .

And $\sum\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$ diverges by Cauchy Condensation test.(Or just by simple comparison with $\frac{1}{n}$ as mentioned in the comments.)